# How to know when object are deleted?

Tags: python, scripting, network

I use blender as a network client. I'm able to know when objects are updated (via [handlers](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example)). But I would like to notify the server when a object (or mesh, animation, etc.) are removed, how can I do this? (Should I keep a list of all objects, and compare with existing?)

Comment: I would try saving a list of object names in a `scene_update_pre` function then compare that with a `scene_update_post` list of objects.